# Stripe custom connect accounts and multiparty payments with subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm currently working on an application where the application owners rent out units to renters. The application owners also sell their rental units to buyers who continue to rent out the unit while paying a fee to the application owners.

My question is - what is the best way to deal with this? Most of the documentation I've seen involves dealing with the payment intents or invoices which would take away most of the automatic functionality that stripe handles for us. (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges)

I would like to modify the subscriptions as documented here https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions

Is there a way to indicate a change in billing for the current cycle without canceling and creating a new subscription?

Comment: In this flow, are you imagining multiple application owners each with their own Stripe account which are connected to your platform? Or is there a single application owner that is the platform?

Comment: @karbi no there is only one application owner, just multiple owners of units. Is there a better place to put this functionality? Like in a webhook when a user makes a payment?